# Return arrow back to orginal position

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9yxf1ckc/12/)

It's a toggle which shows and hides multiple toggled divs. I have it currently set to also toggle the arrow down when the div is opened, however once the div is closed the arrow still stays in a downward position, I want it to return to a rightward position.

```
 $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
```

Full script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // Toggles 1st Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-s").click(function () {
         $(".dtc-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-two-h, dtc-three-h").hide(500);
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // Toggles 2nd Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-two-s").click(function () {
         $(".dtc-two-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-three-h, .dtc-h").hide(500);
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // Toggles 3rd Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-three-s").click(function () {
         $(".dtc-three-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-two-h, .dtc-h").hide(500);
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // #1
     if ($('.dtc-one').is(':visible')) $(this).next().slideDown();
     $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
     // #2
     if ($('.dtc-two').is(':visible')) $(this).next().slideDown();
      $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
     // #3
     if ($('.dtc-three').is(':visible')) $(this).next().slideDown();
      $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the :visible check inside the click function. Like so:

```
 $(".dtc-s").click(function () {
     if($(".dtc-h").is(":visible"))
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
     else
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     $(".dtc-h").slideToggle(500);
     $(".dtc-two-h").hide(500);
     $(".dtc-three-h").hide(500);
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59kz17d9/1/  (I've done it only for the first arrow)

Comment: This is good if the user single clicks the same toggle, however, I want there to be the option of when the user clicks on another toggle it returns the arrow of the previously closed toggle to its rightward position.

Comment: You are a gentlemen and a scholar. Thank you, accepted.

Comment: Let's say they click on the same toggle. I noticed the arrow stays in a downward position unless another is clicked? I took a crack at it, but it disables both toggles. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry about that.. there were some issues with the code. Fixed them here: http://jsfiddle.net/59kz17d9/12/